# How do a ProductController without database error 42S22

Tags: cakephp

I do an app that show some products with price for register people.
When create the product page show me "Database Error"
"Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Product.utype' in 'where clause'"

My ProductsController is like this:

```
class ProductsController extends AppController {


    public function index() {
       $this->Product->recursive = 0;

       $products = $this->Product->find('all');
       $this->set('products', $Product);

    }

    /**
    * view method
    *
    * @throws NotFoundException
    * @param string $id
    * @return void
    */

    public function view($id = null) {
        $this->Product->id = $id;
            if (!$this->Product->exists()) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Product'));
            }
        $this->set('products', $this->Product->read(null, $id));
    }
}
```

And the Model Product.php is like this:

```
class Product extends AppModel {
public $primaryKey = 'id_prod';
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Occurrence' => array(
            'className' => 'Occurrence',
            'foreignKey' => 'occurrence_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Can help me, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the very explicit error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'Product.utype' in 'where clause'"

Your code is looking for the colum 'utype' in the `products` table (which apparently doesn't exist).  If you're not sure where your code is telling it to do that, just do a project-wide search for "utype" and update it to the correct field name.